# Difference between preinstalled and privileged protection level

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

API 23 has renamed permission protection level [`system`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html#PROTECTION_FLAG_SYSTEM) into [`privileged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html#PROTECTION_FLAG_PRIVILEGED). It has also introduced a [`preinstalled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html#PROTECTION_FLAG_PREINSTALLED) protection level.

Does `privileged` implies `preinstalled`? In other words, if an application has access to `privileged` permissions (*i.e.* it is a *system* application), does it have access to `preinstalled` permissions as well, even if those permissions are not listed as `privileged` (only `preinstalled`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be yes, as long as a `privileged` app is part of the system image (*i.e.* pre-installed). The package manager will grant a `preinstalled` permission to what it (internally) calls a *system app*, see [`grantSignaturePermission()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java):

```
if (!allowed && (bp.protectionLevel
        & PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_FLAG_PREINSTALLED) != 0
        && isSystemApp(pkg)) {
    // Any pre-installed system app is allowed to get this permission.
    allowed = true;
}
```

Internally, a *system app* is actually a *pre-installed* app (refactoring is limited to the public API, not in the source), see [`ActivityInfo`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.java):

```
/**
 * Value for {@link #flags}: if set, this application is installed in the
 * device's system image.
 */
public static final int FLAG_SYSTEM = 1<<0;

// Many lines not shown

public boolean isSystemApp() {
    return (flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible for apps to be pre-installed but not have elevated system permissions (e.g. Calculator). This is why the distinction is present between these two flags and why `system` protection level has been deprecated for `privileged`.

Comment: However, as part of the system image, the Calculator app could be granted `preinstalled` protection level permissions: `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE`, `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` and `WRITE_SETTINGS` (I've not checked if it actually request any of them). I suspect privileged apps (in Marshmallow sense, _e.g._ Google Play Services) could also as well, although these permissions are not explicitely flagged as `privileged` in the system's [Manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml).

Comment: This distinction is not really new, other than public API change to represent it plus handling of permission grants.  Back in KK when full SE was enabled in the system, the platform distinguish between system and system-privileged apps.  Prior to that point, it was the combo of pkg signature (had to be signed with the 'platform' key) and the Linux UID (had to be 'system', or 1000).  Now it's really a combo of these and it lumps the apps into different security domains within SE policy.  The big distinction with `preinstalled` here is that the user won't be prompted to grant permissions.